# How do I insert a record into multiple tables in a database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm self studying in C# and SQL Server 2005

I have 3 tables in SQL Server 2005 and I have a form in C# that accept inputs to be saved in the database.

My 3 tables are

- `Hotel` with columns `Hotel No, Hotel Name, Location`
- `Guest` with columns `Guest No, Guest Name, Address`
- `Room` with columns `Room No Room Type, Room Price`

and a junction table where all three tables meet

- `Booking` `Hotel No, Guest No, Room No, Date From, Date To`

I set the relationship that Hotel No, Guest No, Room No are foreign key to Booking table

In my C# form, I have a code that fills the combo box for Hotel Name and Room Type

```
private void FillComboBoxHotelName()
{
   conn.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Hotel", conn);
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
   da.SelectCommand.CommandText = cmd1.CommandText.ToString();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt);
   cmbHotelName.DataSource = dt;
   cmbHotelName.DisplayMember = "Hotel Name";
   cmbHotelName.ValueMember = "HotelNo";
   conn.Close();
}

private void FillComboBoxRoomType()
{
   conn.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Room", conn);
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   da.SelectCommand.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.ToString();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt);
   cmbRoomType.DataSource = dt;
   cmbRoomType.DisplayMember = "Room Type";
   cmbRoomType.ValueMember = "RoomNo";
   conn.Close();
}
```

This code works and the records in my tables in Hotel and in Room fills the combo box in my form, my problem now is how do I store the input values in the Form to my database. Do I need to create a separate Insert query command for each table since the data will go to 3 tables, I am at lost.

My form looks like this:

```
Hotel Name : Combo Box
Guest Name: 
Guest Address:
Date From:
Date To:
Room Type:

Button (Save)
```

Please help I still cant post an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to achieve it Insert Statement and Stored Procedures.

**Insert**

```
 string sql = "INSERT INTO Hotel (Hotel No, Hotel Name, Location) values (@HotelNo,@HotelName,@Location)";
 conn.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@HotelNo", SqlDbType.Int);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@HotelName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.VarChar); 

 cmd.Parameters["@HotelNo"].Value = HotelNo; // Hotel number name in Int
 cmd.Parameters["@HotelName"].Value = HotelName;//Hotel Name in string  
 cmd.Parameters["@Location"].Value = Location;//Location in form of text

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note: Here in code I have made some assumptions that Hotel No is Int, Hotel Name is VarChar and Location is VarChar.

In similar way you can create Insert statement for rest of 2 tables and Insert code into 2 tables.

**Stored procedure**

Create stored procedure to all columns you want to insert into database. Like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourInsertOperation 
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @HotelNo INT, 
  @HotelName VARCHAR(20),
  @Location VARCHAR(20),
--......rest of all your parameter list goes here

AS
  BEGIN
     INSERT INTO resourceTable(column1, column2) VALUES (@HotelNo, @HotelName, @Location )
   --Other 2 insert statements will go here
  End
  Go
```

Once your stored procedure is in place in your Data Base. You can call that stored procedure along with parameters from C# code.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("yourInsertOperation",con);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@HotelNo", SqlDbType.Int);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@HotelName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.VarChar); 
 //Other columns to insert will go here 

 cmd.Parameters["@HotelNo"].Value = HotelNo; // Hotel number name in Int
 cmd.Parameters["@HotelName"].Value = HotelName;//Hotel Name in string  
 cmd.Parameters["@Location"].Value = Location;//Location in form of text
 //Values for columns will go here     

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

To summarize I would suggest you to go with Insert query as it will easy and quick approach to insert into database. And in this you don't have to put efforts in creating SP. But still you have choice to use any or both approaches as your doing it for learning purpose.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this , your right my Hotel no is an INT and the Location is VARCHAR

Comment: I have one more question, its about my HotelNo, in my form I have no Hotel No, I only have Hotel Name in Combo Box, I filled the combo box from the data i have in my database, so is it ok if I will not include it in my insert sql command in C#? Thanks

Comment: Yes that is all right. And In that case you will not have to include Hotel No as parameter in C#.

Comment: I just tried the 1st option you suggested cmd.Parameters.Add("@HotelName", SqlDbType.VarChar); and cmd.Parameters["@HotelName"].Value = HotelName;//Hotel Name in string  I replaced the HotelName into cmbHotelName.SelectedValue since my hotel name is a combo box, then I commented out the HotelNo and the Location, when I Run the program, it returns an Sql Exception "Incorrect syntax near varchar\Incorrect syntax near Name", thanks

Comment: There are multiple possibilities for "Incorrect syntax". 1) Check are providing all necessary columns to insert like HotelName(if you have Location column in Hotel) 2)As error is saying you are may be sending some incorrect character in insert statement

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to solve your question:

1. Create trigger on insert in table Booking which will populate rest of the related tables
2. Put insert SQL in your C# for each involved tables, not the best way to do this but it can be done.
3. Build store procedure to do insert in all 4 tables sequentially. Call this SP from your C# code.

I would prefer to use either 3 or 1 options in order of preference.

Comment: I tried an insert SQL command in for each table, but no record is inserted and a general exception is thrown "Incorrect syntax near 'Name", Where will I build SP? in SQL Server 2005 or in C# and I'll call the method in the Save button

Comment: Show your insert statement along with coding.. Store procedures as well as triggers is a part of SQL Server. One more thing, your column names should not be 2 word, use it like Room_No to avoid unnecessary headaches.

Comment: private void StoreGuest()
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Guest(Guest Name, Location) VALUES('"+txtGuestName.Text+"','"+txtGuestAddress.Text+"')", conn);
            InsertCommand.Connection = conn;
            InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();  (my insert method for guest input)

Comment: just as I suspected: Guest Name should be Guest_Name

Comment: Ok ill change the column name Guest Name into Guest_name in the db, ill message if it solves the problem, thanks

Comment: You need to change all columns name to fit this pattern. Column name should not have space in it.