# Stored procedure for insert update and delete

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am very new to stored procedures. I have a table with an `Id` auto increment. I want to insert, update and delete rows in my table.

What is wrong with my stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[hrm_Languages]
(
    @Name varchar(120),
    @CreatedBy bigint=0,
    @UpdatedBy bigint=0,
    @IsDeleted bit=0
    @ID int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @ID = ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0) + 1
    FROM [dbo].[Languages]

    IF @StatementType = 'Insert'
    BEGIN
       insert into [dbo].[Languages] (Name, CreatedOn, UpdatedOn, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, IsDeleted) 
       values(@Name, DateTime(), DateTime, @CreatedBy, @UpdatedBy, @IsDeleted)

       SELECT @Name
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID, NAME 
                         FROM TableName
                         WHERE NAME = @Name)
      BEGIN

      END
    END

    IF @StatementType = 'Select'
    BEGIN
         select * from [dbo].[Languages]
    END 

    IF @StatementType = 'Update'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Languages] 
        SET Name =  @Name, UpdateOn = DateTime()
        WHERE ID = @ID
    END

    else IF @StatementType = 'Delete'
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM [dbo].[Languages] WHERE ID = @ID
    END
end
```

Getting these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure hrm_Languages, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near '@ID'.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure hrm_Languages, Line 12
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure hrm_Languages, Line 15
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@StatementType".
>
> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure hrm_Languages, Line 17
>   'DateTime' is not a recognized built-in function name.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure hrm_Languages, Line 24
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure hrm_Languages, Line 26
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@StatementType".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure hrm_Languages, Line 31
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@StatementType".
>
> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure hrm_Languages, Line 34
>   'DateTime' is not a recognized built-in function name.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure hrm_Languages, Line 38
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@StatementType".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure hrm_Languages, Line 40
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".

I also want to show message on my web page using label that Name inserted, Nme deleted, NAme already exist

Comment: Where is defined the variable @StatementType?

Comment: it's need to define ?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to insert into the auto increment column. Is that column an identity? If so you are not supposed to insert into it. It also looks like you have not defined StatementType, SQL cannot detect what you want to do. Here is a [link](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2009/06/approaches-to-upsert.html) that might help you get started with the create/update. Personally I would separate delete into another stored procedure.

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is with your sproc?

Comment: My ID auto increment. I am not inserting it.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to have a 'do-it-all' stored procedure like this. Can you explain why do you need to use this approach?. If the code required are simple CRUD operations a well written parameterized query could be of simpler to use and fix than a complex stored procedure. For example, your code above is not able to delete a specific record but only the last one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have corrected stored procedure syntactically. I have written comments for changes I have made. Correct sql will create SP for you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[hrm_Languages]
(
 @Name varchar(120),
 @CreatedBy bigint=0,
 @UpdatedBy bigint=0,
 @IsDeleted bit=0, -- Insert comma
 @StatementType Varchar(20), -- Add variable @StatementType 
 @ID int OUTPUT
)

 AS
 BEGIN



 IF @StatementType = 'Insert'
 BEGIN

 -- As @ID will reset again after insertion of record so following two line are not    needed
 SELECT @ID = ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0) + 1
 FROM [dbo].[Languages]

 SELECT @Name
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID,NAME FROM TableName -- What is table name for 
                 WHERE NAME=@Name)

insert into [dbo].[Languages] (Name,CreatedOn,UpdatedOn,CreatedBy,UpdatedBy,IsDeleted) 
values( @Name, SYSDATETIME(), SYSDATETIME(),  @CreatedBy, @UpdatedBy,@IsDeleted) 
-- SysDateTime is used to get current datetime

SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()    

End

ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Select'
Begin
select * from [dbo].[Languages]
END 

ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Update'
BEGIN
UPDATE [dbo].[Languages] SET
        Name =  @Name, UpdatedOn = SYSDATETIME()
  WHERE ID = @ID
END

ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Delete'
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM [dbo].[Languages] WHERE ID = @ID
END

END
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I pass statement type from asp.net

Comment: It is just a parameter like others. please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394992/how-do-i-insert-a-record-into-multiple-tables-in-a-database/23396054#23396054). Still have any doubt let me know

Comment: @Dnyanesh - This doesn't work for an update or a delete.  The ID is always overwritten.

Comment: @Paddy Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I have corrected the code now and it is working for Insert, Update and delete now.

Comment: Also still a race condition on the insert.  No guarantee that the ID you select first will be the ID inserted.

Comment: @Paddy I have correct return field ID. As I have written in my Answer that I corrected code syntactically. I am agree that after insert query SP should end and rest of SP should be broken in 3 parts for Select, Update and Delete or Select, Update and Delete can be achieved though simple SQL queries and that is why I suggested him [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394992/how-do-i-insert-a-record-into-multiple-tables-in-a-database/23396054#23396054) link. I posted this answer based on question. That is why I wrote word syntactically.

Answer (score 2):

OK, problems with your sproc (after reading it again), please see comments:

```
    -- If you worked for me, I'd be having words about this name, it does not state
    -- what this sproc does.
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[hrm_Languages]
    (
        @Name varchar(120),
        @CreatedBy bigint=0,
        @UpdatedBy bigint=0,
        @IsDeleted bit=0, -- You need a comma here.  You hadn't posted your errors when I answered
                          -- this site isn't really for fixing your compile errors... read
                          -- the error text, it's quite helpful.  Something wrong on line 7...
        @ID int OUTPUT
    )

    AS
    BEGIN

    -- Problem 1.  You are selecting this ID prior to inserting.  This won't always be the 
    -- ID inserted, if your system is getting heavy use.

    SELECT @ID = ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0) + 1
        FROM [dbo].[Languages]

    -- Problem 2. You don't pass in @StatementType - this won't even compile.
    IF @StatementType = 'Insert'
    BEGIN
    insert into [dbo].[Languages] (Name,CreatedOn,UpdatedOn,CreatedBy,UpdatedBy,IsDeleted) 
    values( @Name, DateTime(), DateTime,  @CreatedBy, @UpdatedBy,@IsDeleted)

    -- To get the inserted ID, do the following
    SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


    -- Not sure what the following is for.
    SELECT @Name
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID,NAME FROM TableName
                         WHERE NAME=@Name)
    BEGIN

    END
    END


    -- This is where your sproc should end and the following should be three other sprocs.

    IF @StatementType = 'Select'
    BEGIN
    select * from [dbo].[Languages]
    END 


   -- Problem 3.  You don't seem to be passing in and ID, just for output, and you set the ID in the
   -- first line.  If your system is heavily used, this might just end up updating a newly inserted
    -- row, but most likely will update nothing.

    -- Same goes for the delete below.  Create separate sprocs for doing these things.

    IF @StatementType = 'Update'
    BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[Languages] SET
                Name =  @Name, UpdateOn= DateTime()
          WHERE ID = @ID
    END

    else IF @StatementType = 'Delete'
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[Languages] WHERE ID = @ID
    END
    end
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I pass statement type from asp.net

Comment: @AzharShahid I'm not sure you really read my answer... Split this sproc, doesn't really work as one and then you don't need to pass it.  Otherwise just pass it like you must be doing already for the other parameters...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Paddy's Answer you must use `GetDate()` Instead of `DateTime()` to get the current DateTime.